# взаимное подключение классов dyenhb

Tags: php7

как можно взаимно подключить объекты внутри классов? Данный пример вызывает неконтролируемый рост озу

```
class Class1
{
    private $objFile;

    public function __construct()//: void
    {
        $this->objFile  = new File;
    }
}

/*class Class2
{
    private $objFile;

    public function __construct()//: void
    {
        $this->objFile  = new File;
    }
}*/

class File
{
    private $objClass1;

    public function __construct()//: void
    {
        $this->objClass1  = new Class1;
    }
}

new Class1;
die('fghj');
```

Comment: Как правило такой код говорит о неправильно архитектуре. Один класс может знать о другом. Но оба друг о друге - нет

Comment: я понимаю, мне это интересно в целом, ведь класс заявляется как некая автономная система, что не должно вызывать рекурсии

Comment: рекурсия, она и в Африке рекурсия. Если создание класса вынести в метод, а не конструктор - можно избежать рекурсии, например. Но, т.к. создание другого объекта происходит именно при инициализации текущего - рекурсии не миновать.

Comment: ну да, про функцию я не подумал.